# Error "set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments" when building Blender as Python module on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos, module, cmake, blender

I'm trying to build Blender as a Python module on Mac OS X El Capitan. I'm following [this tutorial](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) for building Blender as Python module and [this tutorial](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Mac) for building Blender in general. My experience is as follows. I can run CMake without any errors with the default settings. However, I want to build Blender as a Python module, and [this page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule) indicates that while I'm running CMake, I need to set:

```
WITH_PYTHON_INSTALL=OFF
WITH_PLAYER=OFF
WITH_PYTHON_MODULE=ON
```

When I set these options as above, I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at source/creator/CMakeLists.txt:223 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties called with incorrect number of arguments.
```

I've tried both command line CMake and CMake GUI, with the same error. I know nothing about CMake, so I'm very lost as to how to resolve this. I've looked at line 223 of `source/creator/CMakeLists.txt` as the error message indicated, and it has the following lines.

```
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(
        blender
        PROPERTIES
            MACOSX_BUNDLE
            LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "${PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS}"
            LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "${PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS_DEBUG}"
    )
endif()
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Looks like value for `MACOSX_BUNDLE` property is missed. According to the property [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE.html), its value may be either *false*-like (e.g. "FALSE") or *true*-like (e.g. "TRUE"). Unsure which one is intended of the author of this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target property [`MACOSX_BUNDLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/MACOSX_BUNDLE.html) does need a parameter:

```
if(APPLE)
    set_target_properties(
        blender
        PROPERTIES
            MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
            LINK_FLAGS_RELEASE "${PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS}"
            LINK_FLAGS_DEBUG "${PLATFORM_LINKFLAGS_DEBUG}"
    )
endif()
```

Seems to be a bug in [`source/creator/CMakeLists.txt`](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/creator/CMakeLists.txt).

This came with a commit a while ago: [[Bf-blender-cvs] [4828c6a] master: cmake: fix generation / install    on OS X, N.B. needs cmake cache rebuild](https://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2014-November/069631.html)

Comment: Wow THANK YOU! Are you involved in the Blender project then? You sound like it.

Comment: @Ray You're welcome. No, I'm not involved in the Blender project. Just - like Tsyvarev - I'm using CMake for a quite a while now and just looking at the error message and the code the problem is very obvious. It started me wondering how this could ever have been working, so I checked the latest version (which still has the problem) and then were looking into when and by whom this was added (which seems to be quite a while ago by Martijn Berger). I just noticed the `if` has changed from `if(WITH_PYTHON_MODULE)` to `if(APPLE)` since then. Seem someone has noticed a problem with the code.

Comment: @Ray Please [report this problem to the Blender project team](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug_), so they may review and fix it.